# push new element into array within hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a hash which, I have keys that uniquely identify each element within the hash.  And within each element, I have an array.  So my question is, how do I put another element inside that array within the hash.

```
{"Apple"=>[1, 5.99], "Banana"=>[5, 9.99]}
```

I'm looping through a result set, and I'm a little bit lost how to add another element to the array...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your hash is called, for example, `hsh`, then the "Apple" array can be accessed by  `hsh["Apple"]`. You can use this like any variable, so to add a value to that array just do `hsh["Apple"] << some_value`. Like so:

```
irb> hsh = { "Apple" => [1, 5.99], "Banana" => [5, 9.99] }
irb> hsh["Apple"] << 9999
=> { "Apple" => [1, 5.99, 9999], "Banana" => [5, 9.99] }
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can order the hash so that lets say the highest price array is first ... while keeping the integrity Cheers for the help btw

Comment: No, in Ruby hashes are unordered, so you cannot "sort" them as such (though this may change in Ruby 1.9). You would need to use a library that extends Hash, like Ruby Facets' Dictionary class: http://github.com/trans/facets/blob/master/lib/more/facets/dictionary.rb

Comment: Is it possible to to do hsh["Apple"] << [9999, 8888], so that you get { "Apple" => [1, 5.99, 9999, 8888], "Banana" => [5, 9.99] }, but without using a loop?

Comment: @user2340939 Use [`Array#concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-concat): `hsh["Apple"].concat([9999, 8888])` or [`Array#push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-push): `hsh["Apple"].push(9999, 8888)`.

Comment: @Jordan I've figured out the first case, but the second one seems handy also.